# Remove wpautop from specific shortcodes only

Tags: shortcode, wp-autop

I need to disable wpautop for some shortcodes. I've read the following on how to disable it:

- http://www.mstoicthemes.com/disable-wpautop-shortcodes/
- https://customcreative.co.uk/resolving-wpautop-and-shortcodes/

However these apply to wpautop in general.

I want to only disable it for *specific* shortcodes, because some shortcodes in my theme rely on that wpautop in order to work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a script out there. The author claims that it removes the `wpautop` form individual specific shorcodes. [You'll find it here.](https://github.com/chiedolabs/shortcode-wpautop-control/blob/master/shortcode-wpautop-control.php)

Add this to your `functions.php` or your plugin like below-

```
// Here I assumed that you kept the name of the PHP script file same 
include "shortcode-wpautop-control.php";
```

And then call the function ike below-

```
chiedolabs_shortcode_wpautop_control(
    array(
        'your_short_code'
    )
);
```

You can also call it like this-

```
// Create first the array of shortcodes from which you wanna remove `wpautop`
$array_of_shortcodes = [ 
    '1st_shortcode', 
    '2nd_shortcode', 
    '3rd_shortcode', 
];
// Then pass the array as parameter when you're calling the function
chiedolabs_shortcode_wpautop_control( $array_of_shortcodes );
```

> *Please note that, this solution isn't tested. Test it before going to production.*

Comment: I've tested and it has an issue with Ad Injection plugin